# How to add properties to an array in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have an array of `Series` objects.

It is a regular array of objects with a function added via code similar to this one :

```js
let series = loadSeriesFromDatabase();
series.getByName = (name)=>{return series;}
```

I tried to add this function(`getByName`) to the SeriesList in many ways now. The closest I've come is documenting series as `{Object}` and adding it like this:

```js
/**
 * @callback GetByNameFn
 * @param {string} name Name of the series
 * @returns {Series} The series that matches given name
 */
/**
 * @typedef {Object} SeriesList
 * @property {GetByNameFn} getByName
 */
/**
 * @type {SeriesList}
 */
let series = [];
```

But that leaves series not as an `Series[]` but as an `Object`, which is not what I want there...

The code above recognizes `getByName` as function, but if I change it to `@typedef {Series[]} SeriesList` it stops working...

Is there a way for it to work with arrays as well or am I just doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken your original attempt and modified the JSDocs to get the result I think that you're looking for.

The ability to have a list of series with the function also being present.

```js
/**
 * @callback GetByNameFn
 * @param {string} name Name of the series
 * @returns {Series} The series that matches given name
 */
/**
 * @typedef {Object} SeriesFunctions
 * @property {GetByNameFn} getByName
 */
/**
 * @typedef {object} Series
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {int} year
 */
/**
 * @type {Series[]&SeriesFunctions}
 */
let series = [];

// Usage
series.getByName();

// Other Usage for the autocomplete fields.
series[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it the way you're doing it is kind of weird.

[image]

How bout if we change it alil bit

```js
/**
 * @typedef Series yow Obj.
 * @property {number} id identifier.
 * @property {string} firstName the firstName.
 * @property {string} lastName the lastName.
 *
 * @callback GetByNameFn
 * @param {string} name Name of the series.
 * @returns {Series} The series that matches given name.
 *
 * @typedef {Array<Series>} SeriesList
 *
 * @typedef SeriesWrapper
 * @property {SeriesList} list The list of all yow `Series`.
 * @property {GetByNameFn} getByName
 *
 */

/**
 * @type {SeriesWrapper}
 */
const data = {
    list: [
            {id:1, firstName: "troll-1", lastName: "trollmon-1"},
            {id:2, firstName: "troll-2", lastName: "trollmon-2"},
            {id:3, firstName: "troll-3", lastName: "trollmon-3"},
            {id:4, firstName: "troll-4", lastName: "trollmon-4"},
        ],
    getByName: function (name) {
        // code
    }
}
```

create an object with a list property and add yow items to it.

```js
const yowObj = {
  list: [],
  func: ()=>
};
```